# How to make slow animation of a div from right to left on click a button in angular 7

Tags: html, css, typescript

I have a button and a div which will be initially hidden.When I toggle the button the div will show and hide.But I need to show/visible the element with animation from right to left slowly and again hide from left to right on toggle the button.Here is the code below

### app.component.html

```
<div style="border:1px solid;padding:10px;" *ngIf="show" class="old">
  Hello how are you
</div>
<button style="position:absolute;left: 28%;top: 16px;" (click)="change()">change</button>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  toggle:boolean = true;
  show:any;
  change(){
    this.show = !this.show;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
this.show = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `*ngIf` directive will dynamically add/remove the whole element. You should try dynamically adding a CSS class to accomplish your animation. Here's an example of dynamically adding a class called "animate":

```html
<div style="border:1px solid;padding:10px;" class="old" [class.animate]="show">
  Hello how are you
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Angular Animations. https://angular.io/guide/animations

You can show/hide the div with *ngIf